# Quicksand transition animation and callback not working

Tags: jquery, callback, internet-explorer-10, quicksand

I've inherited a site that uses the [jQuery Quicksand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html) for data filtering.

I'm having some issues in IE10. The transition animations don't seem to be firing. The sort happens immediately. Also, the callback function that should fire after the sort completes is not firing. All is good in < IE10 and all other browsers that I've tested on.

There are no errors in the console or any indication as to what is failing.

Has anyone found the source of the issue?

[DEMO OF ISSUE](http://jsfiddle.net/EVagr/23/)

```
   function testFunction(){
       alert('test');
   }  

   $('.button').click(function(e) {

       $('.all').quicksand( $('.warm li'), {
           duration: 1000,
           attribute: 'id',
           adjustHeight:false
        },function(){
           testFunction();
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked the problem down. I'll post here incase it might help somebody else.

Line ~64 V.1.2.2

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<7) {
    $sourceParent.html('').append($collection);
    return;
}
```

The substr returns 1 causing the plugin to quit.

I fixed this by removing the substr (**could anyone explain why the substring is necessary?**):

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version<7) {
    $sourceParent.html('').append($collection);
    return;
}
```

which seems to work fine.

Versin 1.3 (which I didn't realise exists) of the plugin uses the following:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 7) {
    $sourceParent.html('').append($collection);
    return;
}
```